# JPA - nested collection element of embedded

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have read JPA specifications - and on section 2.6 (Collections of Embeddeble classes and basic types).

It says that "An embeddable class that is contained within an element collection, must not contain an element collection".

I have a requirement of such a structure. I was wondering what is the standard way to bypass this problem. That is, to have a collection of elements, that their type is an embeddable class, that may contain a collection of elements).

It is important for me to achieve this, while still keeping it as an embeddable class.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use embeddeble. Make it an entity. Why do you want it to be an embeddeble class anyway?

Comment: Explain why this is a requirement.

Comment: Hi, barjsu.

I need this requirement, since I want the entity to be in the context of its surrouning entity. It is the logical thing in my system in this case. In addition, in our DB there could be a situation in which entity A and entity B, both have an embeddeble "C" and I wish that there will be a difference between A.C and B.C. For this, I need C to "know" its father.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered subclassing C?

So you would have C_A and C_B which extends C, and A has a C_A and B has C_B. Then C_A and C_B can reference their parents..

Comment: Thank you for your response.

This is quite good in the technical aspect, but logically I expect C to be a part of its father.